# Browser (and other programs?) opens in the current X session the first time, then on the same session even if launched from another X session

Tags: window-manager, session, virtual-consoles

Please, correct me if the wording of the title is wrong, as I do want to understand the correct terminology too.

The think is, I can swtich using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F *N*</kbd> between different window managers each launched on a different virtual console.

I've always used one, but these days I'm experimenting with a new window manager (XMonad) while still mainly using the one I've used for years (i3), so I'm frequently switching from one to another and viceversa.

In practical terms, I have this config in place:

```
[[ "$XDG_VTNR" -eq 1 ]] && exec i3
[[ "$XDG_VTNR" -eq 2 ]] && exec xmonad
```

One thing I've noticed is that if I open Chromium, the first time it will open in the current session, e.g. i3, but if open another Chromium process, it will open in i3 even if in the meanwhile I switched to xmonad. Same thing the other way around.

Do I have control on this behavior? How?

Answer (score 1):

A modern web browser is a pretty large and complex piece of software. To avoid needing to start it from scratch any more times than absolutely necessary, the designers of Chrome have made it see if the user already has another Chrome process running when it starts up.

If there is an already-running instance, the new instance will just communicate its command line arguments (or whatever information was applicable to its startup) to the already-running instance, and let it open a new window, instead of starting a new copy of the full browser engine. This **process reuse** generally improves the user experience.

Apparently the designers of Chrome didn't consider the possibility that the already-running instance might be part of a different session!

If you run `google-chrome --help`, it will describe some of the possible command line options. The `--user-data-dir=DIR` option might be relevant here: (emphasis mine)

> --user-data-dir=DIR
>
> Specifies the directory that user data (your "profile") is kept in.  Defaults to `$HOME/.config/google-chrome`. **Separate instances of Google  Chrome must use separate user data directories;** repeated invocations of google-chrome will reuse an existing process for a given user data directory.

This suggests specifying a different user data directory to be used on each virtual console might solve your problem. However, you would need to duplicate your user profile, let Chrome sync it over the network, or else start configuring Chrome from scratch on the second virtual console.

Comment: _"designers of Chrome didn't consider the possibility that the already-running instance might be part of a different session!"_ -> [I've opened a ticket](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1516292), fwiw.

Comment: I am certain the designers of Chrome are fairly bright folks.  Your answer points to a reason beyond performance that Chrome behaves the way it does.  Having two different Chrome sessions accessing the same user-data-dir can lead to file corruption without a lot of extra effort.